# Instagram scraping using Python Requests method

Tags: python-requests, instagram

I am trying to scrape videos from an Instagram. For that I am using requests simply to get the contents of the page. Here is my code

```
import requests
res=requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/beberexha/')
```

When I run this code I get the following error

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.facebook.com', port=443): Max retries             exceeded with url: /PTIOfficialVideos/?__tn__=kC-R&eid=ARAa9128wZHlQwlcnTXuGMoZdfpGlUg7HlAmazJdZapqf5prcDaq1Z3SvgcZCUFvDhL8QvWuAq8WY5fs&hc_ref=ARSfgNphbmftBDxo05hb-CjPj9A61GB8NrSvzj-KfzrE17A0x3K6C_JKVnaDEz6jdRY&fref=nf&__xts__%5B0%5D=68.ARD7sfvWL1n2seYYU0zU_fZLCjzxrl3sdWOSyz_41q2ymM4BEEThuXJnYOWjH1lUZhDL22IrLXVuVdIoxWRDXYfPUNBjk322vy28NAXTY-3pxNb_IKrTcbyU62FveS_cO03PMpR6xZIX8R1cjono8E1imy4tLWC3wDam3_3qW-re2prQEKa7IO0AMSxQGi-XVA94186T4uTYM5o5amkd2GUenK8Yg9-SxhjTf6WXrzDmLy_bD4M (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f15d87239e8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: i ran your code, did not see any errors. It may some happened on your network

Comment: yeah it was a network issue. Thanks